# When installing Kubuntu on a laptop with pre-installed windows 10, is there anything i need to preserve?

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, kubuntu, windows-10

Do i wipe the entire physical drive? or just the C: partition?

Is there anything that's essential to keep in order for the laptop to function? and is there anything that might be worth keeping but isn't essential?

that EFI system partition looks like it might need to be there?

will keeping the recovery partitions help me reinstall windows later if i want to change it back to windows? [i'm a bit worried about losing the OEM license]

[image: disk management from windows]

Comment: "When installing Kubuntu on a laptop with pre-installed windows 10, is there anything i need to preserve?" To do what? reinstall windows? Not a question you should ask on a site dedicated to Ubuntu. Use http://superuser.com/ if you need help with windows.

Comment: Why is this question off-topic? It may needs details or clarity as of what the OP intends to have as a final result (dual-boot, only Kubuntu, etc.) but I don't see it as off-topic.

Comment: Kubuntu is an official Ubuntu flavor, this question should be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

if you think you might want to reinstall windows, keep the EFI and both recovery partitions. Delete the C: partition and install ubuntu there. you may then need to change boot priority in system settings.

If you don't want windows, you can erase the whole drive, ubuntu will recreate the efi partition.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest dual-booting Kubuntu with Windows. You should resize "Windows C:" and leave some unallocated space for kubuntu (don't create a new partition). Then, use the unallocated space to create your kubuntu and swap partition. I will link a tutorial for you: [Dual-boot Kubuntu with Windows](http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/11/02/dual-boot-kubuntu-15-10-and-windows-10-on-a-pc-with-uefi-firmware/)

Comment: why should i dual boot?

Comment: You said that there's a chance of reinstalling windows. Why don't you dual-boot? You can keep both systems.

Comment: i already have another computer i use for windows, so it seems a bit redundant and inefficient?